# read data from a file and insert it in the 3rd position of a csv file using bash

Tags: bash, shell, csv

```
File1.txt:     File2.csv:
2018-01-19  2018-01-17,2018-01-18,2018-01-20
1           6,a,f
2           7,b,g
3           8,c,h
4           9,d,i
5           10,e,j

I want my output to be:
2018-01-17,2018-01-18,2018-01-19,2018-01-20
6,a,1,f
7,b,2,g
8,c,3,h
9,d,4,i
10,e,5,j
```

I want to append the column in 3rd position of the csv file.

Comment: Yes it is possible :-P

Answer (score 2):

If your actual data is same as shown sample Input_file, then the following may help you in same.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$0;next} {$2=$2","a[FNR];print}' File1.txt FS="," OFS="," File2.txt
```

Output will be as follows.

```
2018-01-17,2018-01-18,2018-01-19,2018-01-20
6,a,1,f
7,b,2,g
8,c,3,h
9,d,4,i
10,e,5,j
```